# how to generate meta model from entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, criteria

I was trying to do this with hibernate tools, Also with maven like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>br.com.ingenieux.maven.annomojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.jfrog.maven.maven-plugin-anno</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <!-- source output directory -->
                <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/metamodel</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I read posts in this forum, but they do not help.
Can someone help me to make it? I am confused ( I need meta model for creating criteria)

P.s. this link doesn't say how to make it: http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/. I read a lot of info about it, but cannot figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

The maven-processor-plugin requires a dependency, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Although you might want to change the version to '4.3.1.Final'

Comment: it is a crap, I did it what you are suggesting. Already solved it in another way through eclipse. cheers